# UITable view inside view controller , don't change with delegate and datasource implements

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I'm working with swift3 and I need to put a table view inside of view controller, but the table don't change and I don't know the reason :

The delegate and datasource I set and the functions :(

[image]

And my code:

```
import Foundation
import Toast_Swift
public class ViewControllerDataList: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    private var basededatos: BaseDeDatosFirebase!
    private var mensajes: MensajesView!
    private var tags: [ListaTags]?
    let animals: [String] = ["Horse", "Cow", "Camel", "Sheep", "Goat"]
let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"
    @IBOutlet weak var tablaViewTags: UITableView!
    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        basededatos = BaseDeDatosFirebase()
        mensajes = MensajesView(vistaRoot: self)
        tags = basededatos.traerTags()
         print("Tags actuaes \(tags)")
        self.tablaViewTags.delegate=self
        self.tablaViewTags.dataSource=self
        self.tablaViewTags.register(UITableViewCell.self,
                                forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell" )


        // self.tablaViewTags.register(TagViewController.self,
         //                           forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")


    }
    override public func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
          return animals.count
    }

    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // your cell coding
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (tags?.count)!

    }
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
        let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tablaViewTags.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

        // set the text from the data model
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.animals[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
    }


}
```

But the result is empty and I can't understand where I'm going wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return a number of cells different than 0, if you want some cells to show there:

```
public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0 // your number of cell here
    }
```

See the line:
**return 0 // your number of cell here**

Try to put a number greater than 0!

Comment: Same output :( , (  return animals.count)

Comment: Add print(animals.count) and print(tags.count) to check what's going on and see the count returned to the tableView

Comment: Also: try to issue a self.tableViewTags.reloadData().  at the end of the ViewDidLoad

Comment: Oh! I forget put   public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return animals.count

 }